# Sabre Scribe Scripting Specifically Looping

Tags: sabre

Anybody have any tips for looping, and continue? For example, I placed about 2500 pnrs on a queue, and I need to add a remark to each of them. Is it possible for a script to add the remark then move to the next pnr?

For example, I placed about 2500 pnrs on a queue, and I need to add a remark to each of them. Is it possible for a script to add the remark then move to the next pnr?

Answer (score 0):

Loops are supported in Scribe but have to be built manually by creating your own iteration variables and breaking the loop manually when you know the work is complete.

What you are describing is definitely possible, but working in queues can be difficult as there are many possible responses when you try to end the PNRs. You'll have to capture the response to detect whether you need to do something else to get out of the error condition (e.g. if a PNR warning indicates you have to double-end the record).

If possible, its likely simpler to work off the queue by collecting all PNR locators and then looping through that list, adding your remarks, and then ending the PNRs. You'll still have to capture the response to determine if the PNR is actually ended properly, but you won't have to deal with the buggy queue behavior. A basic Scribe loop sample is below. Note that I haven't been a Scribe developer for a while and I did this in Notepad so there might be some errors in here, but hopefully it's a good starting point.

```
DEFINE [ROW=N:8]            ;iteration variable/counter
DEFINE [LOCATOR_FILE=*:60]  ;File Path
DEFINE [TEMP_LOCATOR=*:6]   ;pnr locator variable, read from the temp file
DEFINE [BREAK=*:1]          ;loop breaking variable
OPEN F=[TEMP_LOCATOR] L=0   ;open the file of locators

[BREAK] = ""
[ROW] = 0
REPEAT
  [ROW] = [ROW] + 1
  [TEMP_LOCATOR] = "" ;Reset temp locator variable, this will break our loop
  READ F=[LOCATOR_FILE] R=[ROW] C=1 [TEMP_LOCATOR]
  IF $[TEMP_LOCATOR] = 6 THEN ;test length of locator, if this is 6 chars, you have a good one, pull it up and add your remark
    »"5YOUR REMARK HERE"{ENTER}«
    »ER{ENTER}«
    ;trap errors
     READ F="EMUFIND:" R=0 C=0 [TEMP_LOCATOR] ;read for the locator being present on this screen, which should indicate that the ER was successful - you'll have to trap other errors here though
     IF [@SYSTEM_ERROR] = 0 THEN ;this locator was found, ER appears successful
        »I{ENTER}« ;Ignore this PNR and move to the next one
      ELSE
        [BREAK] = "Y" ;error found afeter ER, break loop. Maybe show a popup box or something, up to you
      ENDIF
  ELSE ;No locator found in file, break the loop
    [BREAK] = "Y"
  ENDIF 
UNTIL [BREAK] = "Y"
CLOSE [LOCATOR_FILE]
```